# Display an image with 'next' and 'previous' buttons, but no loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new to JavaScript, but I have done a lot of reading and just trying.
I have created this code to display an image with 'previous' and 'next' buttons, to scroll through the different pictures. But when it reaches the end, it still allows you to click. I am looking for a code which, when you reach the last picture with 'next', you just can go back to the previous picture with 'back', and vice versa when reaching the first image. I don't want it to loop, I just want it to reach the end so you have to go back with the buttons.

Summary: I want to show 5 pictures: number 1 through 5. The page starts with picture number 3. With the 'Previous button' you can always go to a smaller number, with the next button you can go to a larger number, but never past number 1 or past number 5. So if you reach the end, you have to use the button 'previous' or 'next' (depending on where you are).

I hope I have made myself clear, and sorry if I am not asking it the right way.  I really hope you can help me though.

Thank you!

```js
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="echo.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="imageGallery">    
    <img id="image" src="./images/1.png" />
</div>    
 
<div id="gain"> 
    <button id="previous" type="button">previous</button>    
 <button id="hoger" type="button">next</button>  
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var images = [
            "./images/1.png",
            "./images/2.png",
            "./images/3.png",
            "./images/4.png",
            "./images/5.png",   
        ];

        var imageIndex = 0;

        $("#previous").on("click", function(){          
            imageIndex = (imageIndex-1);    
            $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
        });

        $("#hoger").on("click", function(){
            imageIndex = (imageIndex+1);    
            $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
        });

        $("#image").attr(images[0]);

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the new index:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

     var images = [
       "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/150/100/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/200/100/",
     ];

     var imageIndex = 0,
         iLength = images.length - 1,
         imageEl = $('#image'),
         prevEl = $('#previous'),
         nextEl = $('#hoger');

     prevEl.on("click", function() {
        imageIndex--;

        imageEl.attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

        nextEl.prop('disabled', false);
        prevEl.prop('disabled', !imageIndex);
    });

    nextEl.on("click", function() {
        imageIndex++;

        imageEl.attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

        nextEl.prop('disabled', imageIndex === iLength);
        prevEl.prop('disabled', false);
    });

    prevEl.prop('disabled', true);
    imageEl.attr(images[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageGallery">
  <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
</div>


<div id="gain">
  <button id="previous" type="button">previous</button>

  <button id="hoger" type="button">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, i was not able to make your code work.. am i doing something wrong? It leaves me with clickable buttons, but there is no change in picture?

Comment: I updated my answer to be runnable. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button when you reach the extreme indices of the array. here's an example for the "next" button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

     var images = [
       "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/150/100/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/200/100/",
     ];

     var imageIndex = 0;
     var iLength = images.length - 1;

     $("#previous").on("click", function() {
       imageIndex = (imageIndex - 1);
       $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

       $("#hoger").prop("disabled", false);
     });

     $("#hoger").on("click", function() {
       imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1);
       $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
       if (imageIndex == iLength) {
         $(this).prop("disabled", true);
       }
     });

     $("#image").attr(images[0]);

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageGallery">
  <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
</div>


<div id="gain">
  <button id="previous" type="button">previous</button>

  <button id="hoger" type="button">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but is it correct that when i go back with the button 'previous' the other button stays inactive?

Comment: In my example I implemented the functionality only for the "next" button. For the "previous" button you can implement something similar.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to make the similar functionality for the other button.